# Accesing texture data in vertex shader for instancing

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, webgl, vertex-shader

No debugging needed, just trying to understand a couple of conceptual things.

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLBC2m2_kaI&t=1941s) tutorial to create instanced particles based on a text texture's alpha values. I'm still new to shaders so as you may imagine I have only used `sampler2D` and `texture2D` in the `fragment shader` with the desired `UV`s.

This tutorial is the first place where I have seen a texture used in a `vertex shader`. I do understand that images cannot be 'displayed' on screen by only sampling them in the vertex stage, and he was only trying to throw in a bunch of random points between 0 and 1 through the variable `texCoord` provided by Javascript as follows:

```
const num = 20000;
let texCoord = new Float32Array(num * 2);

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    // -0.5 to 0.5
    let x = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 0.5;
    let y = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 0.5;

    // This is setting the pixel spots for texture picking in verter shader
    texCoord.set([
        x + 0.5, 
        y + 0.5
    ], i * 2);
}
```

I'd like to understand:

1. How the new coordinate system was created for the image (which is a png with transparency) with variable `texCoord` by saving random xy value on each of the num particles? I mean those `texCoord` points do not have a plane in the background to refer the 0 to 1 clipping coordinates from. And since vertex shader runs on each vertex, `texCoord` should have mapped the 0-1 value on the tiny instanced plane instead of the background. Yes?
2. How is it making the "**TEXT**" image somehow occupy the full screen on an imaginary background plane in the vertex shader (through which we extract its alpha). Maybe some ability of the `sampler2D` function that I am missing?

I mean I was expecting a single non-instanced plane would be created that occupies the whole scene and we apply texture to that, only after that we could extract its alpha values. I've spent hours researching and reading and have ran out of articles and tutorials that could  explain this.

I urge you to please explain in layman terms. Thank you.

**Vertex Shader:**

```
// Bring attributes
attribute vec3 offset;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec2 a_lineHeight;

void main() {

    
    vec3 pos = position;
    v_uv = uv;




    // HERE the image is sampled using texCoord points.
    float tex1 = step( .8, texture2D(u_tex1, texCoord).r );
            


    

    v_alpha = tex1;

    float scale = mix(a_lineHeight.x, a_lineHeight.y * 5., u_lineHeight);
    pos.y *= scale;
    pos.x *= u_thickness;

    vec2 origin = texCoord * vec2(1., .5);
    
    float alpha = 1. - v_alpha;
    pos.xy += origin - vec2(0.5, 0.25) + alpha;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
    precision highp float;

varying float v_alpha;
uniform float u_time;    

void main() {
    vec3 color = vec3(1., 1., 1.);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, v_alpha);
}
```

[image]

**Close up of instanced planes:**
[image]

Comment: What is the rendered geometry? What is the primitive type?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm using OGL library's instancing example exactly like shown in the tutorial video that I linked.

Here is how OGL generates instances:
https://github.com/oframe/ogl/blob/master/examples/instancing.html

Comment: @Rabbid76 If I should be clearer, when we use `texture2D(img, uv)` in frag, we have an explicit geometry (plane, cube, sphere.. etc) from which we derive the uv coords to "only" map the texture on this geometry, but in my case where is this screen sized invisible plane that is using the `attribute vec2 texCoord` values to sample on it and then derive its `r` value? gl_Position is not defined till the image is sampled and we are extracting the `r` value from it. In the Vert, please check how `float tex1 ` is being defined for reference.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have added a closeup screenshot in the OP so you can see only those planes are being shown that have their position on a positive `float tex1` value.

Comment: @Rabbid76 My question only relates to how the `texCoord` positions are mapped across the screen on a 0 to 1 coordinate system and how is the system using the entire screen/canvas space to put those points there and at the same time map the image?

If I am correct, `sampler2D` reads the texture and saved all the pixel data in it to be used wherever we need to paste it on a 0 to 1 scale.

But what is making `texCoord` positions to use the entire screen for mapping its values across?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I believe you should close this thread. I am unable to ask it in a better way.

Comment: `texCoord` is not only used to sample the texture, it is also used for the clip space position: `vec2 origin = texCoord * vec2(1., .5);` `pos.xy += origin - vec2(0.5, 0.25) + alpha;`

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you very much, It makes sense now.

Please take a look at this question of mine as well, it's a simple issue and I have included a working sandbox for your assistance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915294/rotating-instanced-geometry-in-local-space-also-rotates-light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the texture lookup has no effect on the position of the geometry.
However, `texCoord` is used not only to sample the texture, but also to calculate the position in clip space:

```c
vec2 origin = texCoord * vec2(1., .5); 
...
pos.xy += origin - vec2(0.5, 0.25) + alpha;
...
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
```

So in this case `texCoord` is used twice. Once in `texture2D` and for the position in the clip space.